# Want to Create facebook app save id, fullname, email sdress of user?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create facebook app that will save full name, id, email address of user.
I tried but nothing is happing please 
What i have to do??

Comment: Is this a facebook app, or a website in which they login in via facebook??

Answer (score 0):

If you request to access visitors 'email', you can get their details. U can achieve it using javascript FB api...